# My mail_type attribute is getting updated.. but i can't figure out why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, parameters, devil

```
def update
    debugger
    @email_blast = EmailBlast.find(params[:id])
    if @email_blast.update_attributes(params[:email_blast])
      debugger
      # changes mail_type here
      flash[:notice] = 'Email Blast Saved.'
      if params[:id] == "1"
        Delayed::Job.enqueue MassEmail.new(params[:email_blast][:subject], params[:email_blast][:body])
      elsif params[:id] == "2"
        Delayed::Job.enqueue OrgBlast.new(params[:email_blast][:subject], params[:email_blast][:body])
      elsif params[:id] == "3"
        Delayed::Job.enqueue MagicEmail.new(params[:email_blast][:subject], params[:email_blast][:body])
      elsif params[:id] == "4"
        Delayed::Job.enqueue OrgMagicEmail.new(params[:email_blast][:subject], params[:email_blast][:body])
      end
      redirect_to edit_admin_email_blast_path(params[:id])
    end
end
```

How strange is that? Once this controller code is passed, @email_blast.mail_type gets changed to "card_holder" . Why would that happen? the Params on the first debugger return :

```
(rdb:407) @email_blast = EmailBlast.find(params[:id])
#<EmailBlast id: 3, subject: "HQMagic Email", body: "asdfasdfasdfasdfas<br />\r\nd<br />\r\nfas<br />\r\ndf<br...", mail_type: "magic_email", created_at: "2010-10-28 14:57:48", updated_at: "2010-11-04 20:51:45">
```

And the second :

```
{"body"=>"asdfasdfasdfasdfas<br />\r\nd<br />\r\nfas<br />\r\ndf<br />\r\nasdf<br />\r\nas<br />\r\ndf<br />\r\nasd<br />\r\nfasd<br />\r\nfa<br />\r\nsd<br />\r\nfasd", "mail_type"=>"card_holders", "id"=>"3", "subject"=>"HQMagic Email"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're calling `update_attributes` and `params[:email_blast][:mail_type]` is defined, then it will be reassigned. You can always set this parameter as protected to avoid this.

Comment: Reassigned? But how would it get reassigned to something not in the params? Interesting. Second question I guess then is how to you set the parameter to be protected?

Comment: @Trip: I think you'll find it *is* in the params.

Comment: Well that is another question isn't it? Look up `attr_protected`.

Comment: @ryan bigg: The first debugger says `mail_type: "magic_email"`, so assuming that it hits update_attributes after that it should stay ` mail_type: "magic_email"` , I would think.. But then once it hits the second debugger, it has changed its mail type to `card_holder` . I don't see it in the first params anywhere for it to say card_holder, I guess. Are there secondary params or something I'm not seeing? Haha thanks for the reply guys.

Comment: So it turns out that attr_protected does work. But it still does  not answer my question, as to how/why that the param is getting changed at all if no **new** mail_type is getting instantiated.